# How to get visitor location without user consent in browser?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, geolocation, google-geolocation

I want to send the email notifications to site admins based upon the user location. For example, if someone sends a request from Atlanta then it will only forward to that Atlanta email ID. So I need to get my website visitor location.

After doing the R&D regarding this, there are few questions in mind that need your opinions.

1- If I used google based geolocation then what should I do with google location access. If user denied access how this application proceed?

2- I've read on many places that IP-based geolocation is less accurate? Also, suggest me best and easy to use free IP based location API.

What do you people suggest to me? Which one method should I go? What should I need to do with browser permissions for location access?

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: No Opinion...Only solution for the problem

Comment: To whom it may concern, instead of marking my question a "-1" a helpful answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the community downvote things, its annoying when they dont offer an explanation.

I believe the most accurate way of doing this is to ask the user for their geolocation, I think google offer an api; https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/

Comment: Ya! agree with your point. I really disappointment to see downvote on my question rather than a help from the community.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.